# Find the lowest value and output username

Tags: php, mysql

I have a members table which (could and should have been normalised) but it hold the following information:

```
**members**
member_id
firstName
lastName
score_1
score_2
score_3
score_4
score_5
score_6
score_7
score_8
```

What I am trying to do is add up all of those scores and find which one is overall the lowest total and THEN output the members `firstName`

I was kindly helped yesterday in getting the lowest value overall but I am struggling to find a way to change the end score to a output a string of the members name.

```
$lowScoreResult = $conn->query("SELECT team_members.team_id, team_members.member_id, members.member_id, members.firstName, members.lastName, SUM(members.score_1) `score_1`, SUM(members.score_2) `score_2`, SUM(members.score_3) `score_3`, SUM(members.score_4) `score_4`, SUM(members.score_5) `score_5`, SUM(members.score_6) `score_6`, SUM(members.score_7) `score_7`, SUM(members.score_8) `score_8`
    FROM team_members 
    JOIN members
    ON team_members.member_id = members.member_id
    WHERE members.dashboard_id = $dashboard_id AND team_members.team_id = $teamSelect");


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($lowScoreResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $low1[] = $row['score_1'];
    $low2[] = $row['score_2'];
    $low3[] = $row['score_3'];
    $low4[] = $row['score_4'];
    $low5[] = $row['score_5'];
    $low6[] = $row['score_6'];
    $low7[] = $row['score_7'];
    $low8[] = $row['score_8'];  
}

$low_score_1 = min($low1);
$low_score_2 = min($low2);
$low_score_3 = min($low3);
$low_score_4 = min($low4);
$low_score_5 = min($low5);
$low_score_6 = min($low6);
$low_score_7 = min($low7);
$low_score_8 = min($low8);

// lowest of the entire set
$t = array($low_score_1,$low_score_2,$low_score_3,$low_score_4,$low_score_5,$low_score_6,$low_score_7,$low_score_8);
```

so the current output form that would be a numeric value which is an over score from a particular column, i,e score_1, score_2 etc as these columns are scores for departments so score_1 is for department 1 score_2 for department 2 etc... I need a way to say like overall value that is shown is from department 1 if it from there...

Comment: do you need to find lowest from the array `$t`

Comment: @NishantNair hey man, iv got the lowest figure which works perfectly. I just need that figure it shows to not be a number but output a string of the column but then change that column name. So the value is a calculation of the lowest score from the scores columns, when it find the lowest score it then I need it to output lowest score found in: department 1 (which is columns score_1) if thats the case

Comment: can you show your sample data and output. it will be easy

Comment: Of Course, so the output would be a single value so what that does above is looks down the columns `score_1, score_2, score_3, score_4, score_5, score_6, score_7, score_8 ` it will find which columns is the lowest overall and output that figure. SO I then need it to output a name instead so like department 1 has the lowest score overall

Comment: What's it going to take to persuade you to redesign your schema?

Comment: @Strawberry I know your right but the trouble is here Im working with iv been provided with :( if these scores where in a separate table i wouldn't be having these issues, this is like that last part then I am done with it.

Comment: Maybe it's time to have a word with the provider.

Comment: I agree and this is something I will be doing after this. Once this is done I can move on from it.

Comment: @Strawberry - right, would you split those 8 scores into 8 separate tables OR have a scores table? its causing me too many headaches and restrictions im going to refactor

Comment: A scores table - of course! `(member_id* score_id* score) * = (component of) PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: So I would have a scores tables with IDs and then a relational table collecting the id from the members and from the scores table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havent tried it on my console but it should give you some idea about caluculatinf the lowest score with fields name details in query itself

```
    select team_members.team_id, team_members.member_id, members.member_id, members.firstName, members.lastName,
    min(score_1),min(score_2),min(score_3),min(score_4),min(score_5),min(score_6),min(score_7),min(score_8)
    from ( select team_members.team_id, team_members.member_id, members.member_id, members.firstName, members.lastName,
            SUM(members.score_1) `score_1`, SUM(members.score_2) `score_2`, SUM(members.score_3) `score_3`, SUM(members.score_4) `score_4`, SUM(members.score_5) `score_5`, SUM(members.score_6) `score_6`, SUM(members.score_7) `score_7`, SUM(members.score_8) `score_8`from
            team_members 
            JOIN members
            ON team_members.member_id = members.member_id
            WHERE members.dashboard_id = $dashboard_id AND team_members.team_id = $teamSelect
     ) as t;
```

Comment: Ok so i get `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in `

Comment: try to use `while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lowScoreResult))`

Comment: can you run the query on your mysql console?

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'team_members 
            JOIN members
            ON team_members.member_id = m' at line 5 `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134160/discussion-between-phpdude-and-nishant-nair).